Resolving conflict between apalike and amsbook
I am encountering an issue with a LaTeX document where the "breakable" package appears to be conflicting with the \tableofcontents command when attempting to add the table of contents to the document.
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cite{guide2001project,project2000guide}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}

And in the references.bib;
@inproceedings{guide2001project,
  title={Project management body of knowledge (pmbok{\textregistered} guide)},
  author={Guide, A},
  booktitle={Project Management Institute},
  volume={11},
  year={2001}
}
@inproceedings{project2000guide,
    title={A guide to the project management body of knowledge (PMBOK Guide).},
    author={Project Management Institute},
    year={2000},
    organization={Project Management Institute}
}

The issues I got:
line 1: Missing control sequence inserted. ...ad {}{}{Contents}}{}\mark {}\endgroup }}{3}
line 1: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. ...ad {}{}{Contents}}{}\mark {}\endgroup }}{3}

My goal is to retain the functionality provided by the "breakable" package while still including both the table of contents and the bibliography in the final output. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you could provide to resolve this compatibility issue.
EDIT [cfr]
Once the .bbl is generated, an invalid .toc is written on next compilation, causing the following compilation to fail with the fatal error given above. I added a \chapter{} to the .toc to make the problem with the addition of the bibliography to the .toc more obvious.
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{1}{chapter}}{2}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{}{Bibliography\begingroup \@temptokena {{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}}\xdef {\chapterrunhead {}{1}{chapter}}{\chapterrunhead {}{1}{chapter}}{\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}\mark {\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}\endgroup }}{3}{}%

This can be shown to be the problem (unsurprisingly) by manually editing the .toc to remove the offending material.
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{1}{chapter}}{2}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{}{Bibliography\begingroup \@temptokena {{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}}\mark {\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}\endgroup }}{3}{}%

The line results from this addition to the .aux:
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{}{Bibliography\begingroup \@temptokena {{\sl  \uppercase {Bibliography}}{\sl  \uppercase {Bibliography}}}\xdef {\chapterrunhead {}{1}{chapter}}{\chapterrunhead {}{1}{chapter}}{\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}\mark {\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}\endgroup }}{3}{}\protected@file@percent }


The code you provided does not reproduce any problems.

You do not provide any example that can be run: you reference an un-supplied references.bib but you have no \cite so the bibliography will be empty. Do you need a bibliography to show this problem? You do not say what error you get.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and David Carlisle: I apologize for the lack of clarity in my previous version of the question. I have now included the error messages and the contents of the references.bib file.

@DavidCarlisle I can reproduce with both current TL and TL 2020.

@ChauLong I've edited your question with some additional details. If you object to these changes, please feel free to roll back. I edited partly to add information, though that's not really needed, and partly to try to head off the close vote since once questions get into the review queues they sometimes meet undeservedly untimely ends.

@cfr. Thank you very much. Is there any hint or a solution from your side?

@ChauLong Not unless you want to manually edit your .toc between runs, no. I advise removing the tcolorbox lines as the error can be reproduced without them. I have a workaround, if you want that? But it isn't a solution really.

@cfr Could you please advise on the procedure to manually edit and obtain the required output in a single execution. Next time can be fail, but it's ok.

@ChauLong See edit below. I don't know whether it produces the required output, but it produces something more-or-less reasonable looking.

I recommend editing your question to remove tcolorbox and to change the title as the conflict is between apalike and amsbook.

As cfr has observed this is unrelated to tcolorbox The issue is that apalike is incompatible with amsbook.  In particular it is not expecting that un-numbered \chapter* entries are written to the table of contents.
The code below moves the \@mkboth call out of the argument of \chapter* (which is a better place anyway) and then the document runs without error.
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{apalike}
\makeatletter
% correct the definition from apalike
\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth
  {\sl\uppercase{\bibname}}{\sl\uppercase{\bibname}}\list
  {\relax}{\setlength{\labelsep}{0em}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

\makeatother
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cite{guide2001project,project2000guide}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}


Thank you .....

@David Carlisle, I appreciate your assistance. Initially, the compilation did not succeed, but after removing the .toc file and attempting it again, it worked as expected. Thank you.

Workaround to reinstate AMS definition:
Not a solution, but a workaround. Use
\NewCommandCopy \thebibliographyorig \thebibliography
\usepackage{apalike}
\DeclareCommandCopy \thebibliography \thebibliographyorig

This restores the AMS bibliography environment. So you keep the citation command \citex etc. but the bibliography format won't be correct (assuming you need apalike).
Workaround by manually editing .toc:
To workaround the problem for a single compilation, compile the file as many times as necessary without running BibTeX. Then run BibTeX. Compile once more. Now open the .toc and find the line
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{}{Bibliography\begingroup \@temptokena {{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}}\xdef {\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}{\chapterrunhead {}{}{Contents}}{}\mark {}\endgroup }}{3}{}%

The line may be longer than this. You want to change it to
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{}{Bibliography\begingroup \@temptokena {{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}{\sl \uppercase {Bibliography}}}\mark {}\endgroup }}{3}{}%

That is, delete everything from \xdef ... to the closing brace right before \mark, but leave the \mark to the end.
This allows a single compilation without error. The result looks all right, but I do not know whether it corresponds to the output you need or not. Compiling a second time produces the error. Once the .bbl is generated, it is crucial to compile only once before editing the .toc and only once after. You could, however, edit the .toc again and get another error-free run, as necessary.
